# Can I check my bonus XP without sleeping in an inn?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Early in chapter 1 you learn that sleeping at an inn lets you use bonus XP earned from doing quests to level up. I’ve had times where I’ve spent money to sleep in an Inn, only to realize I didn't have enough bonus XP to level up.

Is there a way to check how much bonus XP I have saved up before sleeping at an inn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only see bonus XP at an inn. However, you don't have to use the XP if you just want to check it.

Comment: My concern was spending gold to sleep in an inn, then not being able to use any of my bonus XP.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro gold is a non-issue. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322509/56730